# RIDE WebDriverException: Message: session not created exception from unknown error

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I was able to run robot framework tests on Google Chrome using RIDE without issue. However just today I tried to run tests that had run properly before and now I'm getting the following error:

```
Starting test: Bbh-Robot.Test Cases.Search.Search 01 - Basics.Search for Toronto
20161108 13:48:44.163 :  INFO : Opening browser 'googlechrome' to base url 'https://www.google.com/'
20161108 13:48:50.591 :  FAIL : No browser is open
20161108 13:48:50.592 :  WARN : Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: No browser is open
20161108 13:48:50.596 :  FAIL : 
WebDriverException: Message: session not created exception
from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"7332.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.22.397933 (1cab651507b88dec79b2b2a22d1943c01833cc1b),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

Ending test:   Bbh-Robot.Test Cases.Search.Search 01 - Basics.Search for Toronto
```

I thought it might be an issue with chromedriver so I updated to the most recent version (and made sure the executable was included in my Path variable)

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.25/

But it still thinks I'm using 2.22 for some reason and I'm not sure where to proceed. Is there something I can do with RIDE specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing you could do with RIDE (other than a clean restart).

This is a problem with PATH setting that somehow is finding first the old version of chromedriver.

(There could be also a running instance of the old chromedriver.)

Comment: Thanks, turns out I had multiple chromedriver installations on my machine and the one RIDE was using in my PATH was not the one I had updated. I've cleaned up the installations and my PATH and it's working again.